# Word VBA: How do you determine if data pasted into Word will go over to another page?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am copying data from Excel to a Word document. In some cases depending on how much data is copied some of the tables span over more than one landscape page.

**Q** Is there a way to determine if the data I am pasting is going to go over the page, so I can resize it so it fits neatly on one page?

Comment: Does the Excel object you copied has `.width`? Compare it with something like `ThisDocument.PageSetup.PageWidth`?

Comment: Well, since MS Word doesn't really recognize Pages ([here](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html) is a great explanation), you'll have to do some sort of workaround. Dan's answer below seems reasonable enough to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this once before, this is how I did it.

Get the page count before you paste it and store in a variable

Paste the data

Check the page count and adjust if different

Note, pseudo code follows, you should be ok to work it out from this.

```
do while page count > YourVariable
    reduce the text size by 1 point.
    Autofit table columns
Loop
```